# Dynamically display contents of a table without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do I display all the contents of a table without duplicates?

Example:

```
          Table 1
  ______________________
 |    ID     |   VALUE   |
 |     0     |     A     |
 |     1     |     A     |
 |     2     |     B     |
 |     3     |     C     |
```

Expected output:

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE FROM table
```

or use `GROUP BY` statement with `VALUE` column

Answer (score -1):

there is not any duplicate rows. you can use distinct keyword only with values like
`SELECT DISTINCT VALUE FROM XYZ;`
you can do the same using group by

```
SELECT VALUE FROM XYZ GROUP BY VALUE;
```

but this is bullshit. a good developer will not use it.